# Phaser 3: Updating scene variable inside ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, phaser-framework

Im trying to update a variable inside the response of an ajax request to see if the token the user passed is true or not.

**Below is the full scene code:**

```
class InitScene extends Phaser.Scene{

    constructor(){
        super("InitScene")
    }

    preload(){
        this.Token = getParameterByName('Token')||1;
        let validateData ={
            Token:this.Token
        }
        this.correctToken=false;
        $.ajax({
            url: "validateTokenAPI",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(validateData),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // response is a bool
                this.correctToken = response;
                console.log(this.correctToken);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }

    create(){

        let { width, height } = this.sys.game.canvas;
        this.add.text(width/2, height/2,"LOADING...", {font: "28px Arial", fill: "black"}).setOrigin(0.5);

        console.log(this.correctToken);
        if(this.correctToken){
            this.scene.start("NextScene");
        } 
    }

    update(){
        console.log(this.correctToken);
        if(this.correctToken){
            this.scene.start("NextScene");
        } 
    }
}



function getParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Im trying to get the result of the ajax inside the preload function and then use it inside the create or update.

The function `getParameterByName` is simply [plagiarized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) to get the Token from the url;

The preload function sets the value of `this.correctToken` to false initially then sets it to true if the ajax response is true;

The create and update function move the player to the next scene if the Token is correct (I tried both as I thought maybe its due to the async nature of ajax?)

The value of this.correctToken always prints out as `false` inside the create and update but is true inside the `ajax` response

This is not working as I guess the ajax is asynchronous and the value is set in the preload before the response id returned??

I similarly tried putting the ajax in the create and then  using it in the update.

Also adding the ajax in a function and then returning the response did not work.

```
makeValidateAjax(Token){

    let validateData ={
        Token:Token
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "validateTokenAPI",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(validateData),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        success: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit**
Also Calling the `this.scene.start("NextScene");` inside the ajax response doesnt work because the scene is not defined inside the ajax...

**Edit 2**

`#correctToken;`

```
constructor(){
    super("InitScene")
    this.#correctToken=false;
}
```

Also defining the variable in the constructor returns an error when I change it in the ajax response

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot write private member #correctToken to an object whose class did not declare it`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an [EventEmitter](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Events.EventEmitter.html). It could be something [along these lines](https://phasergames.com/phaser-3-dispatching-custom-events/) with a singleton pattern:

```
// eventDispatcher.js
export default class EventDispatcher extends Phaser.Events.EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  static getInstance() {
    if (instance === null) {
        instance = new EventDispatcher();
    }
    return instance;
  }
}

    // InitScene's preload

    this.emitter = EventDispatcher.getInstance();

    // use fat arrow functions to preserve the .this in the ajax's callback
    [...]
    success: (response) => {
      // response is a bool
      this.correctToken = response;
      console.log(this.correctToken);
      this.emitter.emit('CORRECT_TOKEN', this.correctToken);
    },
    [...]

    // create
    this.emitter.on('CORRECT_TOKEN', (token) => {
        this.scene.start("NextScene");
    });
```

As an alternative if you can bother installing one of Rex's plugins (they're all pretty great) I'd go for [Await loader](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/awaitloader/).

I'm mocking up some of the main code, untested (you'll need to set it up like the doc page says). [Full standalone example on github](https://github.com/rexrainbow/phaser3-rex-notes/blob/master/examples/awaitloader/awaitloader.js)

```
const callback = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "validateTokenAPI",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(validateData),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    success: (response) => {
      // response is a bool
      this.correctToken = response;
      console.log(this.correctToken);
      successCallback(); 
    },
    error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
      console.log('error');
      failureCallback();
    }
  });
}
this.load.rexAwait(callback);
```